# Change background colour when plotting categorical data in rasterVis using levelplot

Tags: r, background-color, levelplot, rastervis

I have a categorical data `(lulc)` for a land use land cover having 6 classes. I am trying to plot this data using `levelplot` in `rasterVis`

```
l<-as.factor(lulc)
rat <- levels(l)[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("Agriculture", "Bare land", "Built-up", "Vegetation","Water","Wetland")
levels(lulc) <- rat
levelplot(lulc, col.regions=c("yellow","cyan","pink","green","lightblue","orange"), xlab="", ylab="")
```

But the study area is coastal. Hence I want to show NAs as ocean represented with "lightblue". I tried `panel.background="lightblue"`, but it does not change anything in the plot. What I get is following; [image]

But I want as following;
[image]

Comment: Please get used to providing minimal reproducible examples. Sometimes, questions answer themselves by doing that (e.g. by looking at the examples at `?rasterVis::levelplot`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(rasterVis)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r, par.settings=list(panel.background=list(col="skyblue")))
```

Comment: Thanks @lukeA , it worked. `levelplot(r, par.settings=list(panel.background=list(col="skyblue")),col.regions=c("yellow","cyan","pink","green","lightblue","orange"))`

Comment: For those interested, you can incorporate the ```viridis``` package using ```levelplot(r, par.settings = list(panel.background = list(col="grey27")),col.regions = viridis::magma(n = 1000))```